# save each row of a database as a seperate text file in a directory using perl?

Tags: mysql, arrays, database, perl

I have a database table which is holding various column and rows of data.

1. I want to search one of the columns for keywords. the Column is called ''products".
2. I want to run the query on the table for each keyword and return the results for all rows that contains the keyword.
3. The results for each row should be printed to a seperate file, each file hould take the name as data value contained one of the column of that row (in this case item_id)

I want this done in a loop until all "products" column is searched for all rows of the table.

I have the following code which prints to screen, but all matching rows and columns is returned on the screen at once i,e Not separately to file as i wished (pls read (3) above).

also please note the output formating which is how i want it, i,e seperate lines e.t.c

can anyone help ?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use DBI;
@product = qw( orange apple);   ###an array created for products 
$count = 1;

# Connect to the database
details not provided

  my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$db;host=$db_host",$mysql_user, $mysql_passwd) 
  ||    die "ERROR: Connecting: $DBI::errstr\n";
print "db connected\n";

foreach $product(@product)
  {

    # Prepare the SQL query for execution
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare(<<End_SQL) 
or die "Couldn't prepare statement: $DBI::errstr; stopped";
SELECT item_id, published, modified, availability, summary, 
product, reference FROM $my_table WHERE product LIKE '%$product%'
End_SQL

      # Execute the query
      $sth->execute() or die "Couldn't execute statement: $DBI::errstr; stopped";

    # Fetch each row and print it
    while ( my ($item_id, $published, $modified, $availability, $summary, $product, 
$reference) = $sth->fetchrow_array() )
      {
        print STDOUT ("ITEM ID: $item_id\n Product: $product\n Published: 
$published Modified:$modified\n Availability: $availability\n Summary: $summary\n 
Reference: $reference\n");};


    $count++;

  }
# Disconnect from the database
$dbh->disconnect();
```

Comment: You're printing to `STDOUT`, not a file. Why would it go to a file?

Comment: FYI, you should use `or die`, not `|| die`, because of the different precedence.

Comment: Hi Olaf, thanks for the answer - I know i needed to print to file but wasnt sure how to do it, I only printed STDOUT to show you my code that works so far. thanks your recommendation works. I am evolving this script, I have an aim of actually sending emails for each row returned in a specific format rather then print to file,  but wanted to learn progress the script in stages > print to file first :-) This means I will have other questions on the same project. And thanks Barmar for the tip

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `print STDOUT`, you must create a file and write to that

```perl
open(my $f, ">$item_id") or die "Cannot create file $item_id: $!";
print $f "ITEM ID: $item_id\n Product: $product\n Published: $published Modified:$modified\n Availability: $availability\n Summary: $summary\n Reference: $reference\n";
close($f);
```